# Connect COM port using windows terminal

Tags: batch-file, cmd, terminal, serial-port

Is there any way to connect and communicate with a COM port (e.g. COM4) using windows terminal (Windows 8 <) inbuilt commands or using a batch program?

```
MODE COM4:9600,N,8,1,P
```

Above command displays the confugurations of COM4. But how I can send or receive data?

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/)

Answer (score 10):

use windows powershell

Writing to a Serial Port

```
PS> [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.open()
PS> $port.WriteLine(“Hello world”)
PS> $port.Close()
```

Reading from a Serial Port

```
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.Open()
PS> $port.ReadLine()
```

Comment: My powershell console was waiting forever. I suppose, becouse data in com port has no end of line character

Comment: If the device you connect to does not send line feed characters, I recommend using `.ReadExisting()` instead. Of course, if it's sending stuff, other than Text, you'll need a more sophisticated reading method.

Comment: This is currently the only way to do it, if you are using the latest Powershell. Unless MS decide to also support redirection to ports, and not only (STDIN/ERR etc.)

Comment: For a fully functioning COM usage with powershell, including explanation, please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250070/1147688).

Answer (score 2):

Identify connected COM ports:

```
mode
powershell -c "[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()"
```

Send message with CR/LF:

```
echo hello >COM4
```

Send a file:

```
type file.txt >COM4
```

Read COM port:

```
type COM4
```

The better interactive way is to use Putty or `minicom` from within WSL 1!

Comment: This doesn't work. Using `>COM4` writes to a file called COM4.

Comment: @not2qubit Are you using CMD.EXE or POWERSHELL? Special handling of such names might be only in those shells. If you use Bash or something else...

Comment: I'm using Powershell (*Core*, ie. `pwsh.exe`). I was trying to find more information about the support of special *files* on Windows-11 and powershell, but as usual, very vague and lacking info from MS.

Comment: Only [available redirection](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html) in Powershell.